# function is called before the data is fetched

Tags: node.js, reactjs, async-await

```
 async function getids(){
   await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/scannedproducts/recieve')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("ids are")
    console.log(response.data)
    newids = [response.data]
    setids(newids)
    console.log("product ids are")
  console.log( ids) 
  })
  }
  useEffect(() => { 
    console.log("ujdwfw")
    getids()
    console.log("newids are")
    console.log(newids)
      newids.forEach(element => {
        
          fetchData(element)

      });
  //Add a dependency array.
  },[])
```

I am trying to fetch productids from the server and using the product ids I am gonna fetch the details of the products. but the problem is fetchdata function which fetches the product details is called before the ids are fetched using getids() function. please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the logic into the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function getIds() {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/scannedproducts/recieve');
    response.data?.forEach((element) => fetchData(element));
  }
  getIds();
}, []);
```